# How to make a square framed button with circle inside it on android?

Tags: android

I want to make a square button that have a colored circle inside it, and you can see just the circle and all the rest is transparent.
the purpose is that the button will cover and hide just a small surface but the user can click on all the square frame he have. 
I have a circle button from photoshop, but I can't make it work.
I hope the explanation was clear.
Thank you.

```
 <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/bon8"
      android:layout_width="10dp"
      android:layout_height="10dp"
      android:src="@drawable/b_green" />
```

Comment: And what doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know how to do this

Comment: And what does your b_green piture look like?

Comment: just a circle green button, it's have a circle shape from the photoshop

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to set the button's background:

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/bon8"
  android:layout_width="10dp"
  android:layout_height="10dp"
  android:background="@drawable/b_green" />
```

**---EDIT---**

Upon further discussion, I get what you're really after:

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/bon8"
  android:layout_width="40dp"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:background="@drawable/b_green"
  android:scaleType="center" />
```

Comment: In the xml graphical layout the button changed from circle to round

Comment: Maybe there is a way to expand the boundary of the press beyond the button itself?

Comment: @user2181452 Sounds like you don't actually want a button, but rather an ImageView.  There's nothing special about a button, it's just a view that adds a special background for you.  Use an imageview sized to the area you want and set the src of your image accordingly